# Make failing with 'char 9: unterminated `s' command' when trying to compile gmp-6.2.1 on WIndows

Tags: sed, makefile, gnu-make, gmp

So I am trying to compile GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic library for running `symengine` on my Windows 10 PC.
I was able to install the prerequisites like MinGW, `m4`, `make` and added to `PATH`. These are the following commands I ran

```
cd gmp-6.2.1
./configure --prefix=C:/GMP
make
```

Now when I run make, it fails with the given log

```
/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1'
Making all in tests
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
Making all in devel
make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/tests/devel'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
...
...
Making all in cxx
make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/tests/cxx'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/tests/cxx'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/tests'
Making all in mpn
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/mpn'
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile --tag=CC ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4="m4" gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo add_n | sed 's/_$//'`   -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell  `test -f 'add_n.asm' || echo './'`add_n.asm
libtool: compile:  ../mpn/m4-ccas --m4=m4 gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_add_n -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=broadwell -march=broadwell add_n.asm -o add_n.o
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
No --m4 specified
make[2]: *** [add_n.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/mpn'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Devesh/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems the `sed` expression fails but its not obvious how it should be. The first and second libtool command flags differs in the output- `-m4="m4"` & `-m4=m4` which seems suspect here considering the make rule is

```
.asm.lo:
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=compile --tag=CC $(top_srcdir)/mpn/m4-ccas --m4="$(M4)" $(CCAS) $(COMPILE_FLAGS) `test -f '$<' || echo '$(srcdir)/'`$<
```

(Note that I have installed m4 in msys folder).
Any pointers I should look for to resolve the issue?
Have attached [config.log](https://pastebin.com/vW7JBrUx).

**UPDATE**
The relevant makefile variable in `gmp-6.2.1\mpn` with the sed command looks weird. It seems it should have been expanded beforehand since `$*` is an automatic variable in makefile.

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I$(top_srcdir) \
  -DOPERATION_`echo $* | sed 's/_$$//'`
```

Makefiles in other sub directories like `mpf\` and `mpq\` have got this `AM_CPPFLAGS = -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I$(top_srcdir)`

Examining the `configure` file, it seems there are two places where the sed string is generated, mainly because the `$^` is substituted here.

```
host_os=$*
IFS=$ac_save_IFS
case $host_os in *\ *) host_os=`echo "$host_os" | sed 's/ /-/g'`;; esac
```

```
build_os=$*
IFS=$ac_save_IFS
case $build_os in *\ *) build_os=`echo "$build_os" | sed 's/ /-/g'`;; esac
```

Comment: An `sed` call failed at the input command at that line perhaps? Combinations of backtiks (`\``), and other quoting characters (`'` or '`"`) can be tricky.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the make variable in that relevant makefile (`mpn`) is this ```AM_CPPFLAGS = -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I$(top_srcdir) \
  -DOPERATION_`echo $* | sed 's/_$$//'``` which looks quite weird..

Comment: Where did you get that makefile code from? `$*` should expand to what exactly there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oops, i missed the extra backtick during formatting. Have updated the question. This makefile code is in `gmp-6.2.1\mpn` where it failed.

Comment: Are you working at cygwin (asking because of the `/c/...` paths)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is MInGW only with bash shell. I'm not sure what or when it should expand it.. am checking and don't have much experience in this domain.It seems the there is a line in the `configure` script where this is added .. `case $build_os in *\ *) build_os=\`echo "$build_os" | sed 's/ /-/g'\`;; esac`

Comment: Check the makefile encoding (e.g. with Notepad++), should be UTF8 no BOM ideally.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes it is UTF8 with No BOM.

Comment: I think the investigation is going into incorrect part. This sed invocation most probably comes from `libtool` not the `Makefile`. Output shows that `sed` invocation is correctly transformed into `-DOPERATION` for the next line (the `libtool` invocation) and `sed` script is not long enough to indicate error at char 9. I would check for `sed` invocations within `libtool` itself.

Comment: @raspy, yes I realized that.. strangely running in `sh` instead of `bash` makes this error not come...yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running on `bash` of MINGW64 where the errors were coming. Running on `sh` (installed from MSYS) was successful.